# How to extract values from an associative array and use each value to display in different places

Tags: php

Basically I have this code right now:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $most_viewed) { ?>
  print_r($most_viewed);
<?php } ?>
```

the print_r function displays something like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 13
    [name] => item 1 
    [description_al] => bla bla
    [price] => 18.54
    [date] => 2015-07-19 23:13:48
    [category] => 1
    [brand] => 
    [image] => image-5e053b8f95f8819c37721826631c5c26136f20bfa07fd240aa9d4b3d6f939519-v.jpg
)
Array
(
    [id] => 19
    [name] => item 2
    [description_al] => bla bla bla
    [price] => 13.00
    [date] => 2010-07-20 10:45:16
    [category] => 3
    [brand] => 
    [image] => img-20160217-155609.jpg 
)
```

I want to be able to store from the first array into variables like the name of the product in one variable and the image of the product in another variable so that I can echo them out when ever I need them. I apologize if I have not made myself very clear but I dont know another way to explain my issue, thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this...

```
$names = array();
$images = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $names[] = $row['name'];
  $images[] = $row['image'];
}
```

Comment: No this still gives me both of the titles from the arrays I want to be able to call just one that I want not both at the same time. I did this and and echoed $names[0]; all three show not just one. @kainaw

Comment: In this link you can see the top of the page which has 5 images I want to be able to create something like this:

http://www.thewrap.com/category/tv/

Comment: If you did this correctly, echo $names[0] will echo one and only one value. You obviously did something different.

Comment: You were right I did it was a typo mistake I apologize and thank you, I was doing the same thing bet kept getting more than one result but it was a typo, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question this solution might help:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $most_viewed) { ?>
  $image = $most_viewed['image'];
  unset( $most_viewed['image'] );
  $product_info = $most_viewed;
<?php } ?>
```

Now, $image variable stores your image, whereas $product_info has all other data you need. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo or use a value inside an array, you can simply do this :

**PHP**

```
echo $most_viewed[$index][$key];
```

where key is the object number and `key` is the `property` you want to echo, for instance you want to display the `name` of the `second` object you can acces it like follow :

```
echo $most_viewed[1]['name']; //Will output : item 2
```

an other example, if you want to display the `image` of the first object :

```
echo $most_viewed[0]['image']; //Will output : image-5e053b8f95f8819c37721826631c5c26136f20bfa07fd240aa9d4b3d6f939519-v.jpg
```

note: index of an array start at 0 so if you want to access the first object you will have to use as index 0 for the third object index will be 2 and so on ..

[How to use array in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: I want to create something like this on the top page with 5 images like:

http://www.thewrap.com/category/tv/

Comment: If you have 5 object in your array, you can get the images like this :
echo $most_viewed[0]['image']; echo $most_viewed[1]['image']; echo $most_viewed[2]['image']; echo $most_viewed[3]['image']; echo $most_viewed[4]['image'];

Comment: If you want to know how to place the images like this site : http://www.thewrap.com/category/tv/ post an other question on how to do it in the HTML tag of stackoverflow ;)